# I want to fetch date value in function

Tags: javascript, jquery

> I have use input type = date and I want to fetch the selected date value in function.
>   MY code is

```
<input style='display:none;' type='date' value='<?php echo date(Y-m-d);?>' 
 name='date' id='otherAnswer'/>  

plz help
```

Comment: `$('#otherAnswer').val()` are you try this?

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript you can use:

```
document.getElementById("otherAnswer").value
```

Answer (score 0):

**JQuery**

```js
var val = $("#otherAnswer").val();
console.log(val);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input style='display:none;' type='date' value='2014-02-09' 
 name='date' id='otherAnswer'/>
```

**VanillaJS**

```js
var val = document.getElementById("otherAnswer").value;
console.log(val);
```

```html
<input style='display:none;' type='date' value='2014-02-09' 
 name='date' id='otherAnswer'/>
```